# Reverse Integer python

Tags: python-3.x, reverse

I am trying to solve the [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/solution/) "Reverse Integer" challenge in python.

I took look at the solution they supplied.
Their answer was written in Java.
I do not know why they use the following test-condition:

```java
    if (rev > Integer.MAX_VALUE/10 || (rev == Integer.MAX_VALUE / 10 && pop > 7)) return 0;
    
    if (rev < Integer.MIN_VALUE/10 || (rev == Integer.MIN_VALUE / 10 && pop < -8)) return 0;
```

I wrote my python code without that same test condition.
It failed when I tested a negative number.

```python
     class Solution:
    
        def reverse(self, x: int) -> int:
            rev = 0
            while( x != 0 ):
                pop = x % 10
                x //= 10
                rev = rev * 10 +pop
            print(rev)    
            return rev
```

I do not understand why that particular test-condition exists in their code.

The goal is to reverse the order of digits in an integer.
Some examples are shown below:

#### Example 1:

Input: x = 123
Output: 321

#### Example 2:

Input: x = -123
Output: -321

#### Example 3:

Input: x = 120
Output: 21

#### Example 4:

Input: x = 0
Output: 0

```java
class Solution {
    public int reverse(int x) {
        int rev = 0;
        while (x != 0) {
            int pop = x % 10;
            x /= 10;
            if (rev > Integer.MAX_VALUE/10 || (rev == Integer.MAX_VALUE / 10 && pop > 7)) return 0;
            if (rev < Integer.MIN_VALUE/10 || (rev == Integer.MIN_VALUE / 10 && pop < -8)) return 0;
            rev = rev * 10 + pop;
        }
        return rev;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing the rest of it, but the condition likely handles edge cases near the maximum 32-bit integer value (2147483647) to prevent integer overflows.

Answer (score 0):

Branch conditions are sometimes easier to understand when they are drawn as tree-diagrams instead of one line formulas.

[image: TREE]

Also, we can write the tree like this:

```
├── OR
│   ├── (rev > Integer.MAX_VALUE/10)
│   └── AND
│       ├── rev == Integer.MAX_VALUE / 10
│       └── pop > 7
```

Imagine that `rev` is a container, like a cookie-jar, or a carboard box.

[image: COOKIE_JAR_PICTURE]

There is a maximum number of cookies which can be crammed into the cookie jar.

When `rev == Integer.MAX_VALUE` it means that the cookie jar is full.

The condition `rev == Integer.MAX_VALUE/ 10` is represent the idea that the cookie-jar can only fit one more cookie.

Instead of stuffing cookies into cookie jars, we are stuffing digits (such as `5`) into an integer.

The integer is the container.

Note that when you append zero to an integer in base 10, it is the same as multiplying by 10. For example, `25` becomes `250`

Suppose that the largest integer allowed is `2,147,483,647`

Note that `214,748,364` is equal to `2,147,483,647 / 10`

When you divide by 10, the decimal part of the number is discarded.

When `rev` is `214,748,364`, then you can append any integer the right-most end, as long as that digit is less than or equal to 7.

| Old Element | New Element | New Container | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 214748364 | 0 | 2147483640 | VALID |
| 214748364 | 1 | 2147483641 | VALID |
| 214748364 | 2 | 2147483642 | VALID |
| 214748364 | 3 | 2147483643 | VALID |
| 214748364 | 4 | 2147483644 | VALID |
| 214748364 | 5 | 2147483645 | VALID |
| 214748364 | 6 | 2147483646 | VALID |
| 214748364 | 7 | 2147483647 | VALID |
| 214748364 | 8 | 2147483648 | TOO BIG |
| 214748364 | 9 | 2147483649 | TOO BIG |

The "*status*" column in the table above

In their code, when they wrote `(pop > 7)` it probably should have been `(pop > Integer.MAX_VALUE % 10)`

Suppose that the largest integer allowed is `2,147,483,647`

Then, `2,147,483,647 % 10` is equal to `7`.

There are many, many different ways to reverse the digits of a number.

One solution, in python, is shown below:

```python
x = int(reversed(str(x)))
```

Comment: thank you for your explains, its super clear :)